# How to refresh the screen continuously and update it in real time

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I want to write a C program on linux which refreshes the screen continuously and updates it in real time (for example, similar to the `top` command in the terminal). Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Comment: Take a look to [NCURSES](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Comment: Have a look at [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

Comment: Still in development, but could also take a look at Termbox https://code.google.com/p/termbox/

Answer (score 32):

To keep it portable across terminal types, you need to use a library such as [ncurses](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/). Check out that link, its an exhaustive tutorial.

Here is a basic program that prints an ever increasing number at the top left corner of the screen:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main (void)

{
        /* compile with gcc -lncurses file.c */
        int c = 0;
        /* Init ncurses mode */
        initscr ();
        /* Hide cursor */
        curs_set (0);
        while (c < 1000) {
                /* Print at row 0, col 0 */
                mvprintw (0, 0, "%d", c++);
                refresh ();
                sleep (1);
        }
        /* End ncurses mode */
        endwin();
        return 0;
}
```

Thats how you refresh the window. Now, if you want to display rows of data as `top` does, the data you display needs to be maintained in an ordered data-structure (depending on your data, it maybe something as simple as an array or a linked list). You would have to sort the data based on whatever your logic dictates and re-write to the window (as shown in the example above) after a `clear()` or `wclear()`.

Answer (score 8):

If you are under `xterm` or `VT100` compatible, you can make use of [console codes](http://linux.die.net/man/4/console_codes), example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* for sleep */

#define update() printf("\033[H\033[J")
#define gotoxy(x, y) printf("\033[%d;%dH", x, y)

int main(void)
{
    update();
    puts("Hello");
    puts("Line 2");
    sleep(2);
    gotoxy(0, 0);
    puts("Line 1");
    sleep(2);
    return(0);
}
```

You can do almost everything with escape sequences, but [as pointed out in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses): `ncurses` optimizes screen changes, in order to reduce the latency experienced when using remote shells.

Comment: You'd better use `fputs(..., stdout)` instead of `printf(...)`.

Comment: @LS_dev, you are right, edited

Comment: I was referring in `#define`... In `main`, `puts` would be enough.

Comment: @LS_dev, as you can see `gotoxy()` (and many other sequences) receives parameters, `fputs()` is not a good choice ;)

Comment: Referring `clear`! Small things, not important, sorry! ;)

Comment: The `\033[H` code is correct and appropriate here. But defining it to be equal to `clear()` can be deceiving. Since it doesn't clear the screen (like the code `\033[2J` does. It simply updates it. So `update()` would be better suited.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra, you are right, edited ;)

Answer (score 7):

Ncurses may be the way to go. Since you said program, then ncurses, c, c++. Look into all of it. But if you plan on doing just something "shelL" related, go with perl.

Edit: To add onto my point, here's some modules that can give you an idea.

http://metacpan.org/pod/Curses::UI::Dialog::Progress

http://metacpan.org/pod/Smart::Comments

```
window.clrtobot()
```

And for good measure, a call for curses to clear the whole window.

Answer (score 5):

As the others have said, you probably want to look at the ncurses library. But if you don't need advanced formatting, perhaps something simple like this can be enough:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int number = 0;
    while (1) {
        ++number;
        printf("\rThe number is now %d.", number);
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your situation, you can use the "watch" command on the command line to get quick views like top. You can also watch multiple commands at the same time.

ex:

```
watch 'ls -l <somefile>; ps -fC <someprocess>; ./some_script'
```

Answer (score 3):

As well as using the ncurses library to do the screen handling, if you want to update it "continuously" and "in real time" you're probably going to want to look into timers and signal handling, too. `timer_create()` and `timer_settime()` can get you a timer going, and then you can use `sigaction()` to set a handler function to trap the `SIGALRM` signal and do your updating.

EDIT: Here's some sample code, as requested:

```
#define TIMESTEP 200000000

timer_t SetTimer(void) {
    struct itimerspec new_its;
    struct sigevent sevp;
    timer_t main_timer;

    sevp.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sevp.sigev_signo = SIGALRM;
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sevp, &main_timer);

    new_its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    new_its.it_interval.tv_nsec = TIMESTEP;
    new_its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    new_its.it_value.tv_nsec = TIMESTEP;

    timer_settime(main_timer, 0, &new_its, NULL);
    return main_timer;
}

void SetSignals(void) {
    struct sigaction sa;

    /*  Fill in sigaction struct  */

    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

    /*  Set signal handler  */

    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);
}

void handler(int signum) {
    switch (signum) {
    case SIGALRM:
        update_stuff();    /*  Do your updating here  */
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a sample code of this?

Comment: @sr01853: Sure, I edited the answer to add an example.