# Clear or replace console output

Tags: c++, linux

I'm doing an alarm clock in C++ and am currently working on the program's output. The program will output the alarm time and current time on separate lines, as such:

Your alarm is set for: 12:12 AM

It is currently: 7:08:32 PM

I have the program output once per second to keep track of the current time accurately, however rather than having new lines appear once per second, I was wondering if there would be a way to keep the current time on a single line, and have that line change accordingly to make the program more readable. I'm using cout for this program. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh the screen continuously and update it in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18458064/608639), [Modifying text in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6958972/608639), [Updating/Refreshing text displayed on the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23205280/608639), etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Change Output From "cout"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388628/c-change-output-from-cout)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying text in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958972/modifying-text-in-the-terminal)

Comment: When looking at the answers in the commented duplicates, I'd prefer the ones discussing the `ncurses` library.  Disregard the answers suggesting to hard-code escape codes into your program - or even worse, suggesting `system("clear");` or `system("cls");` (seriously?!) .

Comment: You should try using ncurses library. It's capable of continuous refresh without blinking and other cool options.